# Add Sticky post attribute to CPT UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to define a post as either featured or sticky to display in a different way on my WordPress build.

CPT UI gave me:

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_projects');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_projects() {
register_post_type('projects', array(
'label' => 'Projects',
'description' => 'Add individual projects',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => true),
'query_var' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','post-formats'),
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Projects',
  'singular_name' => 'Project',
  'menu_name' => 'Projects',
  'add_new' => 'Add Project',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Project',
  'new_item' => 'New Project',
  'view' => 'View Project',
  'view_item' => 'View Project',
  'search_items' => 'Search Projects',
  'not_found' => 'No Projects Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Projects Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Project',
)
) ); }
```

I tried adding in     `'meta_key' => 'Sticky', &     'meta_key' => 'on',` however neither were successful.

How would I go about adding an option to the front end of each post to make it featured or sticky?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware custom post types are not supported for sticky posts. However I managed to get around it with this function.

```
<?php 
function wpb_cpt_sticky_at_top( $posts ) {

    // apply it on the archives only
    if ( is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive() ) {
        global $wp_query;

        $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        $num_posts = count( $posts );
        $sticky_offset = 0;

        // Find the sticky posts
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_posts; $i++) {

            // Put sticky posts at the top of the posts array
            if ( in_array( $posts[$i]->ID, $sticky_posts ) ) {
                $sticky_post = $posts[$i];

                // Remove sticky from current position
                array_splice( $posts, $i, 1 );

                // Move to front, after other stickies
                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array($sticky_post) );
                $sticky_offset++;

                // Remove post from sticky posts array
                $offset = array_search($sticky_post->ID, $sticky_posts);
                unset( $sticky_posts[$offset] );
            }
        }

        // Look for more sticky posts if needed
        if ( !empty( $sticky_posts) ) {

            $stickies = get_posts( array(
                'post__in' => $sticky_posts,
                'post_type' => $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'nopaging' => true
            ) );

            foreach ( $stickies as $sticky_post ) {
                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array( $sticky_post ) );
                $sticky_offset++;
            }
        }

    }

    return $posts;
}

add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpb_cpt_sticky_at_top' );

// Add sticky class in article title to style sticky posts differently

function cpt_sticky_class($classes) {
      if ( is_sticky() ) : 
      $classes[] = 'sticky';
          return $classes;
    endif; 
    return $classes;
        }
add_filter('post_class', 'cpt_sticky_class');
```

This will add a meta checkbox in all CPT posts that will say 'Sticky' and will float to the  top in that CPT archive